# node.js mongoose how to 'push' String to model scheme?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

pls help :)

```
user.update({
    "somedata" : somedata._somevar
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
    } else {
        callback(null, user);
    }
});
```

How i can not rewrite somedata with somevar, but 'push' like simple array thing?
To get this result:

```
somedata : [
    'data_one',
    'data_two',
        etc...
]
```

user Schema:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "somedata" : {
        "type" : Array,
        "default" : "empty"
    }
});
```

Thnks!

Comment: You need to add more data in the question. What does your mongoose schema look like?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot about this :) Post updated, user Schema added.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's correct, but I usually just use literals in Schema. Ie. `{somedata: []}` or even `{data: [{name: String, age: Number}]}`. As for assigning to actual users, I'm sure you can just assign it an array, if that's your question. Like `user.data = ['my', 'string', 'array']`. Or like this: `if(!user.data) user.data = []; user.push('item'); user.push('another item');` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! Thanks :)

```
user.update({
    $push : { "somedata" : somedata._somevar }
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
    } else {
        callback(null, user);
    }
});
```